# Cooking potatoes curry

Tags: potatoes

I use my method which is i peeled potates and washed them with water. Then, i cut them and washed them with water again before cook them. Is it right or wrong? Because my aunty said, don't wash them again after cutting. Can you give me suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! This is a bit tricky - it borders on "opinion-based", meaning that there might be not just *one* way to do it "right", especially as it's unclear what constitutes "wrong" in your (or your auntie's) opinion. Nutritient loss? Rinsing off starch? Please take the [tour] and visit our [help], then come back to [edit] this question to make it clearer, thanks!

Comment: It's pretty clear she's asking if it's proper technique for potato curry to wash the potatoes after cutting them up.

Answer (score 2):

When you wash or soak cut potatoes, you are [rinsing away a good deal of starch](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/remove-starch-potatoes-11537.html) that has come to the surface during and after the cutting process (it's the white stuff that gets on your knife and fingers when cutting).

In a potato curry, removing this starch by washing the cut pieces *can* result in a broth that's not as rich or thick, but I would try it both ways to see if it actually makes a notable difference - if your curry tastes watery, washing away the surface starches of the prepped potatoes is to blame.